# (node:50868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

So I am trying to make a simple level-XP system in discord where it would level up every time someone sends a message. I have this for my level system in my message event. Level is defined as the schema of it as I am using Mongoose. There problem is it can save it the person has no data and they send a message it creates data like XP: 0 level: 1 but afterwards won't update again when they send a message to like say XP: 25 etc. The error is (node:50868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of null

```
level1.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.author.id }, async (err, res) => {
  if(err) return console.error(err)

  if(!res) {
    let newdata = new level1({
      guildID: message.guild.id,
      userID: message.author.id,
      level: 1,
      xp: 0,
      totalxp: 0,
      time: Date.now()
    })

    newdata.save()
    res = newdata
  } else {

    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}`)) return;

  const generate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18);
    (await level1.findOneAndUpdate({ guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.guild.id }, { totalxp: res.totalxp += generate, xp: res.xp + generate, time: Date.now() })).save()

  if(res.xp >= res.level * 300) {
    (await level1.findOneAndUpdate({ guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.guild.id }, { level: res.level++, xp: 0 })).save()
    message.channel.send(`Congratulations you are now Level **${res.level}**, ${message.author}`);
  }
}

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to add `.save()` to `findOneAndUpdate`

`findOneAndUpdate` will update the record in db without the need of using `.save()`

so your update queries should be like

```
await level1.findOneAndUpdate(
    { guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.guild.id }, // filter part
    { totalxp: res.totalxp += generate, xp: res.xp + generate, time: Date.now() } // update part
)
```

and

```
await level1.findOneAndUpdate(
    { guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.guild.id },
    { level: res.level++, xp: 0 }
)
```

I think this could do the trick

regarding the logic of the code, I think we can combine both the update queries in one query using some logic before the update query

we can use this logic in the else part

```
const generate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18);

let updatePart = {
    totalxp: (res.totalxp || 0) + generate, // this will be updated in all cases, even if the level is upgraded or not
    time: Date.now() // this will also be updated in all cases
}

let msg = ''; // a message to be returned after the update

if (res.xp + generate >= res.level * 300) {
    // if experience + random generate is greater than level * 300, 
    // then we need to update the level, and set the xp to 0

    updatePart.level = res.level++;
    updatePart.xp = 0;

    // update the msg with the new level
    msg = `Congratulations you are now Level **${res.level++}**, ${message.author}`

} else {
    // if experience + random generate is lower than level * 300, this means the level is the same
    // then we need to update the xp only
    updatePart.xp = res.xp + generate;

    // update the msg
    msg = `Experience updated successfully`
}

// just do the update query once, 
// If we just need to update the document, 
// we can use updateOne instead of findOneAndUpdate

await level1.updateOne( // you can use findOneAndUpdate also, it's okay
    { guildID: message.guild.id, userID: message.guild.id }, // filter part
    updatePart // this is the update object
)

message.channel.send(msg);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Now I get this error. ```(node:20616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "totalxp"```. @Mohammed

Comment: ah sorry, I've update my answer, it should be `totalxp: (res.totalxp || 0) + generate` instead of `totalxp: res.totalxp += generate`

Comment: I tried it and also saw the ```xp: (res.xp || 0) + generate``` I made that and still it says msg and stuff but doesn't save to the database? @Mohammed Yousry

Comment: are you sure we are getting inside the else condition? 
Also Could you provide the output of console.log(res)?